# Why does my text not show a value with a OnPropertyChanged function?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I get no text now when I try to bind a label in my XAML. It seems like it does not find the "setvalue" of my string `Forename` in my viewmodel for some reason. When my `Forename` tries to set different values I write it in the log, but it doesn't find either of them. Not the if, not the if else and not the else either.

(`myInt` is an `int` with the value of `0`, `1` or `2`.  It is `0` by default.)

I have a viewmodel with this code:

```
public class MenuViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));    
        }
    }

    string info;

    public string Forename 
    {
        get { return info; }
        set 
        {
            if (myInt == 0) 
            {
                info = "TextOne";
                OnPropertyChanged("Forename");
            }
            else if (myInt == 1)
            {
                info = "TextTwo";
                OnPropertyChanged("Forename");
            }
            else 
            {
                info = "TextThree";
                OnPropertyChanged("Forename");
            }

            // When I try to write out these if, else if, else in the log 
            // I get nothing. So it does not seem to reach them.
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I receive it on my contentpage + its XAML:

```
public MenuPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new MenuViewModel();
}
```

With the XAML:

```
<Label Text = "{Binding Forename}" />
```

Comment: Forename's getter returns the value of info.  You never initialize a value for info, and you never set Forename to a value, so info will never be anything other than null.  If would probably make more sense to put your if/then into your getter, and not have a setter at all.

Comment: yes! it works now. it writes out the result 10 times a second though, why is that and how can i change that? maybe it doesnt matter but for it to work so frequently maybe isnt so good for the app?

Comment: No idea, you haven't shown the code where you are setting the value.